# Is creating an interface to a class a way to prevent to access the setters of this same class?

Tags: java, methods, encapsulation

Let's say I have the class `User` with the attributes `name`, `email` etc.. In my code, I still want to be able to update that information, but I don't want anyone being able to reach the setters methods directly.

```
public class User implements UserOperations {

    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name 
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name;
    }
}
```

```
public interface UserOperations {

     String getName();
}
```

Is creating an interface with only the getters methods a good idea or should I change the access-capabilities of the User's method from `public` to `private` or `protected`?

I tried to implement the interface, but I feel as if it's not the best solution there is.

Comment: Nothing will stop you from casting to `User`, so no, this does not provide "protection", it will just be speedbump. That is also not the purpose of interfaces.

Comment: Anything "public" is accessible from anywhere! Moreover an interface is always public and is a "tool" for classes to group methods for purpose, it is not an access modifier or preventer Class definition access modifiers and method access modifiers public protected private and default are the main key to creating unobtainable classes and methods. If you want to prevent an interface from accessing a method , use the "final" keyword on the method signature. E.g. public final int getInt(){

Comment: @SamuelMarchant An interface is not always public, the methods defined in an interface are public, but the interface itself doesn't need to be. Also defining a method as final doesn't prevent access to a method, it just prevents overriding of the method.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel There isn't enough space in one comment for the last piece of it you have described! thx.

Answer (score 1):

SOLID principles are the key answer for your concernes.
In a way you want to separate logic of managing the state and managing operations you should create much more classes.

Here is possible solution:
Your class User is pojo now. Making **User** class **immutable** will make impossible to change objects of this class.

To perform changes on object you would need to create a new object with new internal state. Usually it would be done with some other class as a facade which will perform required operations and return new object.

Effectively you would need some class **UserOperationManager**
which will handle all required access to object

This approach will cover single responsibility and interface segregation principle

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll try to see how I can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by anteastra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77209890/642706), and the [Comment by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77209841/is-creating-an-interface-to-a-class-a-way-to-prevent-to-access-the-setters-of-th#comment136114646_77209841), are both correct.

### Produce an immutable object, with a copy of current state

If your app has some places where `User` should be mutable, and other places where `User` should be immutable, then make another class for the immutable situation.

If the main purpose of this other class is to transparently communicate immutable data, use a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```java
public record UserImmutable ( String name ) implements UserOperations 
{
    public String getName() {
        return this.name ;
    }
}
```

Add a `toUserImmutable()` method to your mutable class. This method produces an instance of our record with data based on the current state of our mutable object.

```java
public class User implements UserOperations {

    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name ;
    }

    public UserImmutable toUserImmutable() {
        return new UserImmutable( this.name ) ;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UserImmutable userImmutable = user.toUserImmutable() ;  // Capture an immutable copy of the mutable object’s state.
```

Or, use the more general interface.

```
UserOperations userImmutable = user.toUserImmutable() ;  // Capture an immutable copy of the mutable object’s state.
```

Of course your immutable copy is just that, a copy. If the original mutable object changes its state, the immutable copy does *not* change. Whether that is a good thing or a bad thing depends on the specifics of your app’s situation.

Answer (score 0):

As already said above it is better to use immutable state (mark the fields final) and exclude setter, if still for some reason you need to leave setter, then you can make it private and use it in those methods that are declared in the public interface